# Moving inner div over its parents and neighbours(overflow and z index dosent help)

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

Hello guys im really new to JS and CSS, and im just testing skills in gamedevelopment...

[removed link]

if you try pressing "W" key several times you ll see that the blue div when he leaves zone of a parent div he goes under the neighbour div... how to solve this?

please help

Comment: what is the desired result? i.e. what was it supposed to do?

Comment: don't make game in dom, try canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answer:
Remove the z-index of the parent boxes (the red ones)

now the inner workings:

The problem with setting a z-index to siblings and their children, is that each time you set a z-index to a parent, all of it's children's z-indexes will now be relative to the parent's.

i.e. if one sibling's child has a higher z-index than another sibling's child, while both parents have their own z-index, those children will not be in the same hierarchy.

try removing the z-indexes of the red boxes, and only having the z-index on the children.

given that this is the result you seek.

Answer (score -1):

change `overflow :visible` to `overflow: hidden;` for `board_cell` css rule

Comment: nope.. it doesnt help... it just hides the blue ones under the red ones.. what i need so that blue ones always showen over the red ones even if they are not parents

Answer (score -1):

put the z-index of the red squares 0 and of the blue squares 1
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp